# How to determine if a type is of type HashSet and how to cast it?

Tags: c#, .net

I have someone on GitHub asking for the ability to compare HashSets for my project on GitHub: https://github.com/GregFinzer/Compare-Net-Objects/.  I need to be able to determine if a type is a hash set and then get the enumerator.  I am not sure what to cast it to.  Here is what I have for an IList:

```
private bool IsIList(Type type)
{
    return (typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(type));
}


private void CompareIList(object object1, object object2, string breadCrumb)
{
    IList ilist1 = object1 as IList;
    IList ilist2 = object2 as IList;

    if (ilist1 == null) //This should never happen, null check happens one level up
        throw new ArgumentNullException("object1");

    if (ilist2 == null) //This should never happen, null check happens one level up
        throw new ArgumentNullException("object2");

    try
    {
        _parents.Add(object1);
        _parents.Add(object2);

        //Objects must be the same length
        if (ilist1.Count != ilist2.Count)
        {
            Differences.Add(string.Format("object1{0}.Count != object2{0}.Count ({1},{2})", breadCrumb,
                                              ilist1.Count, ilist2.Count));

            if (Differences.Count >= MaxDifferences)
                return;
        }

        IEnumerator enumerator1 = ilist1.GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerator enumerator2 = ilist2.GetEnumerator();
        int count = 0;

        while (enumerator1.MoveNext() && enumerator2.MoveNext())
        {
            string currentBreadCrumb = AddBreadCrumb(breadCrumb, string.Empty, string.Empty, count);

            Compare(enumerator1.Current, enumerator2.Current, currentBreadCrumb);

            if (Differences.Count >= MaxDifferences)
                return;

            count++;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        _parents.Remove(object1);
        _parents.Remove(object2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `ICollection`?

Comment: That doesn't work:

public bool IsHashSet(Type type)
{
 return (typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(type));
}

[Test]
public void IsHashSet()
{
 HashSet<int> hashSet = new HashSet<int>();
 Type type = hashSet.GetType();
 Assert.IsTrue(_compare.IsHashSet(type));
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is enough works directly with the `ISet<T>`, the `ICollection<T>` or the `IEnumerable<T>` generic interfaces instead of the `HashSet<T>`. You can detect these types using the following approach:

```
// ...
    Type t = typeof(HashSet<int>);
    bool test1 = GenericClassifier.IsICollection(t); // true
    bool test2 = GenericClassifier.IsIEnumerable(t); // true
    bool test3 = GenericClassifier.IsISet(t); // true
}
//
public static class GenericClassifier {
    public static bool IsICollection(Type type) {
        return Array.Exists(type.GetInterfaces(), IsGenericCollectionType);
    }
    public static bool IsIEnumerable(Type type) {
        return Array.Exists(type.GetInterfaces(), IsGenericEnumerableType);
    }
    public static bool IsISet(Type type) {
        return Array.Exists(type.GetInterfaces(), IsGenericSetType);
    }
    static bool IsGenericCollectionType(Type type) {
        return type.IsGenericType && (typeof(ICollection<>) == type.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
    }
    static bool IsGenericEnumerableType(Type type) {
        return type.IsGenericType && (typeof(IEnumerable<>) == type.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
    }
    static bool IsGenericSetType(Type type) {
        return type.IsGenericType && (typeof(ISet<>) == type.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
    }
}
```

Comment: This will also catch `Dictionary` types

Comment: @GaspardP Yes, and there is nothing wrong here because of the Dictionary is both `IEnumerable` and `ICollection`. Moreover, due to the task specifics, it is not needed to work with `HashSet` exactly. Thus I do not see any reason for downvoting.

Comment: The issue I have is with the title of the question then, "How to determine if a type is of type HashSet and how to cast it?" implies that the accepted answer will provide a test to figure out if the type is a `HashMap`. In this case the test will not distinguish `HashMap` from `Dictionary`.

Comment: @GaspardP Working exactly with the HashSet<T> type narrows the resulting solution, but literally, you are correct. Thus, I have updated my answer a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over `GetInterfaces()` and check whether it implements an interface where `IsGenericType` is true and `GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ISet<>)`

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer does not distinguish from `Dictionary` type and possibly other subclasses of `ICollection` and `IEnumerable`. This works better:

```
Type t1 = typeof(HashSet<int>);
bool test1 = t1.IsGenericType && 
    t1.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(HashSet<>); // true

Type t2 = typeof(Dictionary<int, string>);
bool test2 = t2.IsGenericType && 
    t2.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(HashSet<>); // false

Type t3 = typeof(int);
bool test3 = t3.IsGenericType && 
    t3.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(HashSet<>); // false
```

Answer (score -1):

This is built in to HashSets... Use the method SymmetricExceptWith.  There are other built in comparisons as well. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336848.aspx

Comment: I need to use reflection to figure out the differences.